# Register Mac to Azure AD without enrolling in Intune

Tags: mac, entra-id

I am looking to find out if Mac devices can be **registered** (not joined) to Azure AD. I've tried to research on both Google and this site, but all information I was able to find pertained to joining Azure AD and/or enrolling the device in Intune. Note that we don't need the users to be able to sign into the device with Azure AD credentials. We just need the device to show up registered in Azure AD.

These mac devices are contractor devices and are joined to another MDM so they can't be enrolled in our Intune. They've tried signing in with their credentials for our company using the Company Portal app, but that doesn't work because they are managed by their own MDM.

With Windows devices that we don't want to join or enroll in Intune, the device will sometimes get registered simply by activating an M365 application or using Access Work or School in settings. Our contractors only have business basic licenses though so their office applications are web based. We could try temporarily giving them an E3/E5 license to install and activate office on their Mac and see if it gets registered - does anyone think this would work?

The reason we want to do this is that we are moving to AzureVPN as a solution and need to be able to install it on contractor devices. Our policies require a device to at least show compliant in Azure AD for use. See this (Windows) device which is registered, has no MDM, and shows compliant:

[Device is registered and has no MDM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL2UD.jpg)

We'd like to accomplish the same thing with a Mac.

Knowing that, maybe I am looking at this the wrong way. If there's any alternative way to do it, I'm all ears. Apologies if this is a bit of a wall of text, hopefully I have provided the right details. Thanks in advance for any help you all can provide!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have macOS registered and compliant.

Only managed devices can be compliant.

This is by design, because Intune MDM client (Windows) or Company Portal app (macOS)  has to validate device for compliance policies before marking device as compliant. And it can't do that for an unmanaged device.

This is stated in [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/require-managed-devices#require-device-to-be-marked-as-compliant)

> This option requires a device to be registered with Azure AD, and also to be marked as compliant by:
>
> - Intune
> - A third-party mobile device management (MDM) system that
>   manages Windows 10 devices via Azure AD integration. Third-party MDM
>   systems for device OS types other than Windows 10 are not supported.

This also (probably) explains a reason you have registered Windows device marked as compliance